# If $\phi^{-1}(0)$ in $\phi:X\rightarrow Spec\; \mathbb{C}[t]$ is a complete intersection, then is $\phi$ flat?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory

This is a simple question so I am hoping the answer is quite simple as well.

Suppose $\phi:X\rightarrow Spec\; \mathbb{C}[t]$ is a map such that the algebraic variety $\phi^{-1}(0)$ is a complete intersection. Does that mean $\phi$ is flat?

Note that I am not imposing any conditions on $X$.

$$
$$

Comment: Dear math-visitor, it took me somr time to understand what you meant: you should replace "so that the algebraic variety..." by "*such* that the algebraic variety..."

Comment: Thank you Georges! I was trying to formulate the question and at the same time, type this question. I will change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.
If you take for $X$ the subvariety   $X\subset \mathbb A^2(\mathbb C)$ defined by $xy=0$, the first projection $\phi: X\to \mathbb A^1_\mathbb C=Spec(\mathbb C[t])$ is not flat because the dimension of the fibers $\phi^{-1}(t)$ jumps at $t=0$, nevertheless  $\phi^{-1}(0)\cong \mathbb A^1(\mathbb C)$ is a complete intersection.

**Edit**
It is easy to see purely algebraically that $\phi$ is not flat.
Indeed, the dual map $\phi^*:\mathbb C[t]\to \mathbb C[x,y]/(xy):t\mapsto \bar x$ is not flat because over a PID (like $\mathbb C[t]$) the flat modules are exactly the torsion-free modules and here the element $\bar y\in \mathbb C[x,y]$ is a torsion element: $t\cdot \bar y=\bar x \bar y=0$

Comment: Thank you Georges! Your answers are always helpful!

Comment: @math-visitor: it may be worth to note a kind of converse: if $X$ is smooth and $\phi$ is flat, then $\phi^{-1}(0)$ is locally complete intersection.

Comment: Of course, and thank you QiL! =)

Comment: Dear @QiL, thank you for that comment. However I don't find it evident: is it in  some algebraic geometry book?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg:this is because $\phi^{-1}(0)=V(t)$ is a hypersurface in $X$.

Comment: Thank you, @QiL. Actually this the justification I gave to myself in my example: I wonder why I asked  this in my preceding comment?! So $\phi^{-1}(0)$ is actually a global complete intersection in $X$?

Comment: Yes @GeorgesElencwajg you are right. When $X$ is smooth, it is a locally complete intersection (by definition !), so the same holds for $\phi^{-1}(0)$.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for but here's it is: http://www.emis.de/journals/UIAM/actamath/PDF/35-243-246.pdf

Comment: Dear math-visitor: this seems to be a very well-written  aricle. Thanks a lot, especially since it is in a journal to which I don't have access. +1

Comment: You're welcome Georges!